# Python. np.vectorize. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to understand np.vectorize.  I use two simple examples for this purpose.
First code

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(['Simple','something'])
func = np.vectorize(lambda val: list(val))
func(X)
```

get error, but I want to convert from str to chars

> setting an array element with a sequence

But second code don't get error

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(['123','354'])
func = np.vectorize(lambda val: int(val))
func(X)
```

and get convertation good result

> array([123, 354])

Why? I am so confused.

Comment: `np.vectorize`, at least in the simple call like this, requires a function with a scalar (single) output.  Your first case produces a list.  Are you looking at `np.vectorize` just out of curiosity, or do you have a real need for it?  Keep in mind that it does not promise any speed improvement.  A simple list comprehension would be better in cases like this.

Comment: just out of curiosity :) Okay, I understood that np.vectorize has scalar (not list) output

Comment: `X.astype(int)` does this conversion much, much, faster.